# MySQL table cache

Tags: mysql, caching, optimization

I am a bit new to this, so I need insight on how cache works.

I am doing some analytics work so I am only interested in data between some date-time. I have to perform `count()`, `max()`, `avg()` on various columns (total 20 odd queries for same data range).

I want to optimize my queries so that the `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate'` table is cached and subsequent queries are performed on that data.

Can I do something and save processing or it would happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically assuming you have enough memory dedicated to MySQL to hold the data.  Having an index on `startdate` and `enddate` would be crucial as well.

Also, keep in mind that you can have multiple aggregate functions in a single query - so you may be able to do fewer than 20 queries to get the data you need if they are all over the same date range.